# Multiple vpn connection for VPN Gateway

Tags: networking, vpn, gateway

All the PCs in the LAN currently connects to internet via a single VPN Connection:

```
                    +------+
Devices +---------> | TUN0 |+-----> ISP ROUTER
                    +------+
```

Now, I need to connect the devices to the internet via 2 VPN Connection; some of them to connect via tun0, while others via tun1.

```
                    +------+
Device 1 +--------> | TUN0 |
                           |+------> ISP ROUTER   
Device 2 +--------> | TUN1 |
                    +------+
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Where is the tun0 interface located on? I don't understand your drawing tbh.... With 'ISP Router' you are referring to the box you got from your ISP, right?

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the box that the ISP gave me. tun0 and tun1 are located on a linux pc that is acting as a router.

Comment: So currently all LAN members have their default Gateway configured to be the Linux box you mentioned? Are there already running two (Open?)VPN daemons? Shall all traffic be routed through the tunnel(s)?

Comment: Yes, the linux box is configured as the default gateway. Yes, both the daemons are running on the linux box. Yes, all the traffic should be routed through the tunnel. My idea in case if it wasn't possible to just route all the traffic via one VPN interface and just run a second VPN on the device under the main VPN on the linux gateway, but this is cause the network to slow down excessively.